# Extracting only characters from list items REGEX

Tags: python, regex, list

I am practising regex and I would like to extract only characters from this list

```
text=['aQx12', 'aub 6 5']
```

I want to ignore the numbers and the white spaces and only keep the letters. The desired output is as follows

```
text=['aQx', 'aub']
```

I tried the below code but it is not working properly

```
import re 

text=['aQx12', 'aub 6 5']

r = re.compile("\D")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, text))

print(newlist)
```

Can someone tell me what I need to fix

Comment: You can try this: ```newlist = [j for t in text for j in re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+",t) ]```

Comment: `\D` should probably be `[\D\S]`

Comment: @Sujay Thank you. Your answer worked.

Comment: You do not even need regex. Have you checked [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68761365/3832970)?

Answer (score 1):

You're testing the entire string, not individual characters. You need to filter the characters in the strings.

Also, `\D` matches anything that isn't a digit, so it will include whitespace in the result. You want to match only letters, which is `[a-z]`.

```
r = re.compile(r'[a-z]', re.I)
newlist = ["".join(filter(r.match, s)) for s in text]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any chars other than letters in a list comprehension.

No regex solution:

```py
print( [''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s)) for s in ['aQx12', 'aub 6 5']] )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bYOFN7). Here is a regex based demo:

```
import re 
text=['aQx12', 'aub 6 5']
newlist = [re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]+', '', x) for x in text]
print(newlist)
# => ['aQx', 'aub']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZDFOI8)

If you need to handle any Unicode letters, use

```
re.sub(r'[\W\d_]+', '', x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/76k7nN/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` then join the matches instead of using `re.match` and `filter`, also use `[a-zA-Z]` to get only the alphabets.

```py
>>> [''.join(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', t)) for t in text]
['aQx', 'aub']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a regex as well:

```
from string import ascii_letters

text=['aQx12', 'aub 6 5']


>>> [''.join([c for c in sl if c in ascii_letters]) for sl in text]
['aQx', 'aub']
```